# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-(n-k)^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-(n-k)^{2}}$ converges? I think not, I used the integral:
$\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}e^{-(x-y)^{2}}dxdy\rightarrow \infty$
then the series diverges. What do you think?

Comment: A lot simpler than that! Look at inner sum, put $k=n$. You get $1$. So inner sum is bigger than $1$. Then it is comparison with harmonic series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \exp(-(n-k)^2) > \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta_{k,n} \exp(-(n-k)^2) = \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: Upvoted! Would you mind giving [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106496/de-moivres-theorem-motivation-and-origins) a try?